# Contact Form not allow to enter data inside fields

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, popup, contact-form

Have one big problem that dont can resolve myself, because it seems more complex that i can handle myself. I have Contact Form created, and inserted CSS class that trigger popup window, with contact form. But when contact form is loaded, it dont allow me to enter any data inside fields, because looks like it is locked in some way. For example:

[image]

when press "**Contacto**" button (from right on image) is opening this popup window taht contain phone number about customer, and also another button called "**Enviar email**" that when is pressed trigger a new popup that contain contact form. This is code from that button:

```
<form>
<input class="spu-open-1734" type="button" value="Enviar email" />
</form>
```

class `spu-open-1734` is CSS class generated by [Popupups plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/popups/).

When Contact Form is loaded into popup, it dont allow to enter any content into fields, like fields are blurred, and not allowing to enter nothing. Example [here](https://www.asistesocial.es/resume/victoria-hlta9gy-auxiliar-de-enfermeria-vizcaya/)

[image]

Its really weird, because if upper code is inserted into Wordpress page for ex. its working fine, and allow to enter data. See here on this [test page](https://www.asistesocial.es/test-contact-form/).

Comment: Are you still having this problem?

Comment: yes, still have this problem.. as you can see, no answers on this qeustion. :)